# How to add date to MySQL table name?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am now writing some query's for a cronjob.
The query's need to create a table like an existing table. 
Only it has to add the date of the day after (without separations) to the tablename.

I have come up with this solution:
Code to date of tomorrow:

```
$date = date ('dmY');
$date = strtotime(date("dmY", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");
```

The query:

```
$queryvc = "CREATE TABLE vervanger$date LIKE vervanger;
            INSERT vervanger$date SELECT * FROM vervanger";
```

When I echo this in PHP it gives the result I want, but the query doesn't execute. And I think it is because of the fact that I do not 'cut out' the `$date` from the query which is normally a must. Does anyone have a solution to this?

The query will be run once a week with a cronjob, but in the cronjob all tables with dates more than few months back will also be deleted. That way the database will not grow TOO big.

Comment: Why do you want that? PS: usually mysql drivers cannot perform several queries at once. "But the query doesn't execute." --- the thing is that it's a not a query, but a *queries*.

Comment: Why not just add a timestamp to each record and clean it up that way? (assuming you want to do this to keep your DB clean)

Comment: Dynamically cobbling together table names is a ginormous red flag. What are you trying to do? Why a dynamic table name?

Comment: INSERT  INTO is needed in query syntax ??

Comment: The dynamic tablename is used to keep the database clean. At that way, we can see all guests that visited that specific meeting(assuming dates are dates of meetings) 

adding a timestamp wouldn't make it much easier on first sight of the database. 

@zerkms so you are saying, that i should try running query by query, and not like now, 'grouped'?

Comment: @SliQz: I'm saying that at first you need to check the mysql driver documentation at first, and the error logs at second. Programming is a precise thing, don't try just random things supposing something would help. PS: "The dynamic tablename is used to keep the database clean" --- creating million tables helps to keep the DB clean, right.

Comment: Generating more and more tables is exactly the opposite of "keeping the database clean". A clean database is one with a sensible, normalized, ***fixed*** schema which you can run queries against.

Comment: @ArunKillu When i echo the query the way it is, and input the query straight into the database it does all it needs to do. Thats why i haven't added that yet

Comment: @SliQz: it is not a **QUERY**, it is a **QUERIES**. Plural.

Comment: @deceze I know what you mean, but it is not meant to run queries against. It just has to be visible straight from the "dashboard", wich date the tables contain

Comment: @SliQz: to know "wich date the tables contain" - you may just perform a `SELECT` query from the table.

Comment: If you do not run queries against your database, you cannot get any data out of it. Even a simple `SELECT * FROM table` is a query. There's no such thing as "directly viewing MySQL data on a dashboard", it always goes through an application layer which adds some query logic. But, whatever, feel free to paint yourself into any corner you like. Just saying you're doing it wrong.

Comment: i know that thats a query. The point is, that it will not be vieuwable for anyone besides the db admin. Wich will not be looking at it for more than 5, maybe 6 times a year. To explain the "dashboard" item. I use XAMPP. so when you'd go to localhost/phpmyadmin you will see the databases, then you click on the desired database, and THATS Where i want to see the tables including dates.

Comment: @SliQz: you better hope that the guy who will support the system after you don't have your phone number.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you want something and you ask yourself how it is programmed does not qualify as a programming question per-se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1st create archive database (vervanger_archive) .
- 2nd at original
  base if you dont have set DATE_ADD (adding timestamp for each row).
- 3rd SET 1 cron task once upon a day to move OLD rows from Original
  table to the archive table.

Creating tables with timestamp names is bad choice..

Comment: Thank you Sir for answering my question quite clear. Creating archive tables now. @ the rest, i think i wasn't clear enough to you with the question. I just want to reset all tables after the cronjob. So this archive idea is just something i hadn't thought of yet. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Rather to create a table maybe you can give a date to each record in this table. Then you can delete the entries that are too old.

After that if you still want to create an archive table... you may consider this documentation about [multiple statements in one statement string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php). You have to use [mysqli.multi-query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: I know it might be odd to all of you, but i do NOT want the date IN the tables. i want it in the TABLENAME thus by recreating a copy of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to choose creating multiple tables as this would be a nightmare.

But just that you are aware multiple queries are not executed in one operation. You can do this using mysqli::multi_query. Then again, make sure that the db user has been granted access to create tables.

My suggestion would be either to add an additional column "Date" set as an index and refresh this data (delete stale insert new or INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or INSERT IGNORE as your application needs to record this data). If, data is stored monthly etc., you might want to research MySQL buckets.