# Creating a table with the name being a variable date?

Tags: mysql

I wanted to create a table with the name of the table being a date. When I gather stock data for that day, I wanted to store it like this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$mysqli->query(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$date`(ID INT Primary Key)"
);
```

That way I will have a database like:

```
2013-5-1: AAPL | 400 | 400K
          MFST | 30  | 1M
          GOOG | 700 | 2M
2013-5-2: ...
```

I think it would be easier to store information like this, but I see a similar question to this was closed.

[How to add date to MySQL table name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011049/how-to-add-date-to-mysql-table-name)

> "Generating more and more tables is exactly the opposite of "keeping
>   the database clean". A clean database is one with a sensible,
>   normalized, fixed schema which you can run queries against."

If this is not the right way to do it, could someone suggest what would be? Many people commenting on this question stated that this was not a "clean" solution?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Link to the similar, closed question?

Comment: I just added it. Sorry.

Comment: Why not just add a date column?

Comment: But all the stocks are on the same date, doesn't that seem redundant? Also when finding the table, I would have to search all the tables. Isn't a table name supposed to describe what is in it. And it's the stocks for that date.

Comment: You could argue the other way around: why not add a table for each combination of date and stock name? Then you could have the tables AAPL-2013-5-1, MFST-2013-5-1 and so forth. The reason is that you'll never be able to write any useful queries against them. By splitting you data over several tables depending on a date, how would you, say, calculate the average stock price for a whole month?

Comment: @mzedeler These are earnings dates, the stocks don't need to be compared, the data is completely separate. Specific stocks have specific earnings dates.

Comment: The stocks are on the same date, so the date is redundant, yes, but the pair (date, stock name) is always unique. That's a sign that you are on the right track.

Comment: So the answer is it's okay or not okay to do this? The database could get very large with tables.

Comment: The thing is that database tables can't really be used as buckets the way you describe. If your application ever needs to be extended, this kind of database schema will ruin your day.

Comment: I will think that through. Can someone answer so I can mark a correct answer or should I delete the question? Does the question have any future value for visitors?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about getting large tables, because the amount of data is more or less the same with your schema. If you hit a performance problem using just *one* table, you surely will using many of them (but still depending on the use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not split your data into several tables. This will become a maintenance nightmare, even though it might seem sensible to do so at first.

I suggest you create a date column that holds the information you currently want to put into the table name. Databases are pretty clever in storing dates efficiently. Just make sure to use the right datatype, not a string. By adding an index to that column you will also not get a performance penalty when querying.

What you gain is full flexibility in querying. There will be virtually no limits to the data you can extract from a table like this. You can join with other tables based on date ranges etc. This will not be possible (or at least much more complicated and cumbersome) when you split the data by date into tables. For example, it will not even be easy to just get the average of some value over a week, month or year.

If - and that's depending on the real amount of data you will collect - some time in the future the data grows dramatically, to more than several million rows I would estimate - you can have a look at the data partitioning features MySQL offers out of the box. However, I would not advise to use them immediately, unless you already have a clearly cut growth model for the data.

In my experience there is very seldom a real need for this technique in most cases. I have worked with tables in the 100s of gigabytes range, with tables having millions of rows. It is all a matter of good indexing and carefully crafted queries when the data gets huge.

Comment: I will think this through, it seems everyone is saying it will get out of hand, which I can definitely see. Thanks for everyone's opinions.

Comment: Oh so then I would SELECT with the date being a specific date I see.

Comment: Yes, or with a range etc. Much more flexible. Don't worry too much about the theoretical limitations of the technology. They are much farther out than you might think now :)